# Cascading LOVS - default values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have two cascading LOVs. After changing value of my first LOV in second LOV appropriate values are populated.

[image]

First LOV:
name - P2_DEPTNO

```
select dname, deptno  
from dept  
order by 1;
```

Second LOV:
name - P2_EMPNO

```
select ename, empno  
from emp  
where deptno = :P2_DEPTNO;
```

cascading LOV parent - P2_DEPTNO

What should I add to set default value of second LOV (first row from query) after changing first LOV value?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible with popup lovs.  Can you use select lists?  In that case it will default to the top result if you turn off display extra values / display null values.

Comment: @RLOG, thx, but one list must be Popup LOV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the correct answer on the Oracle community forum.

> This is possible in only one case, because I'm more familiar with this type of issue in my project.
>   We need to change the second item type i,e "Empno" item type from Pop-up LOV to Select-List.
>   Also make null setting changes as per given below :

[image]

> On DEMO works proper.

[image]

> Please note that this will CAN NOT be achieved with item type as POP-UP LOV directly using simple step. To make this work using you need to work on POP-UP LOV we need so much custom changes, like DYnamic Actions , JS Code, Asynchronous calls to DB.

Source - https://community.oracle.com/thread/4048009

Author - **EnigmaCoder**

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have Display Null Value set to No and it should use the first value in the list. (Although I am not sure what it will do with Popup LOV).